# configure sphinxbase or pocketsphinx for android in ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu

I need  to implement  speech to text offline functionality for my android apps, I found library sphinxbase i tried to installed in ubuntu but something went wrong and the error occured.
I have download the both package of sphinxbase and pockectsphinx and placed in same directory , As document says i ran ./autogen.sh file successfuly after this one message occur to run make command to compile packages after make command there is some error occur

```
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libsphinxbase.a /usr/local/lib/libsphinxbase.a
libtool: install: chmod 644 /usr/local/lib/libsphinxbase.a
libtool: install: ranlib /usr/local/lib/libsphinxbase.a/bin/bash: /home/speech: No such file or directory
make[4]: *** [install-libLTLIBRARIES] Error 127
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/speech to text/Untitled Folder/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase'
make[3]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/speech to text/Untitled Folder/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase'
make[2]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/speech to text/Untitled Folder/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase'
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/speech to text/Untitled Folder/sphinxbase/src'
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Strip off the space in the directory name.

Try renaming **"speech to text" to "speechtotext"**.